# VSC and terminal ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-terminal

i have windows and im using terminal ubuntu and every time i try to use code either in root or in user this appears
To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.
im studying programming and this is griding my gears down

i have tried various things installing disinstalling wsl , wsl2 ,PATH i dont know what else to do to make code . work , vsc already has the wsl installed , and code is installed in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing based on the error text you've provided here - sounds like the solution is to:

1. Uninstall VS Code in WSL.
2. Install VS Code on Windows.

I'm pretty sure that VSCode has an extension[^1] available to it which allows the Windows instance of VSCode to be used even for code that resides inside your WSL instance. This allows VSCode to run extensions et. al. inside the WSL instance, but run the frontend directly in Windows.

[^1] *This might just be built in to VSCode, I can't recall*